# new.function replacement for Python 3

Tags: function, python-3.x, new-operator

I have some existing code that I am porting to Python 3.  This code constructs a python function object from a python code object and a list of default arguments using the new module as follows:

```
my_function = new.function( code_object, globals(), None, default_values );
```

The result of this is a new function which I can call with impunity:

```
fn_result = my_function( my_args, **my_keyargs );
```

Since the "new" module is deprecated, I cannot use it in Python3.  Also, I need a solution that starts with a code object because I am storing the code object outside of the python code (long explanation of why).

Answer (score 3):

You use [`types.FunctionType`](http://docs.python.org/library/types.html?highlight=functiontype#types.FunctionType) instead, as documented in the `new` modules [official documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/new.html). This works under Python 2 as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I have read the documentation on the new module which pointed me to types.FunctionType.  What I don't understand is how to use this name to create a function instance that uses the code object.  An example would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Progress:  it seems that types.FunctionType is not just a name, but a reference(?) to a 'function' class that has a constructor, which I can use to create a new function instance.  But, where is the documentation for that constructor?

Comment: @user1231679: look at the source code for `new.py`: `from types import FunctionType as function`. It's exactly the same thing, just `types.FunctionType` rather than `new.function`.

Comment: Thanks, Lennart & Chris.  Very helpful!I wonder if some of this information could be better documented (i.e. outside of the source code).

Comment: Yes, these types should have their profile documented. In this case however, it is a straight replacement.